# How can one fix the reference types in a broken EA Repository

Tags: types, installation, enterprise-architect

We have an installation of a Cloud-Based EA-Repository where obviously the script for preparing the Database was not run completely.
The team has been able to work for a long time (surprising to me!), but now they want to setup Auto-Counters on requirements and the requirement type is not available for example: there are no entries in t_stereotypes.

I exported the reference data (Project->Data Management->Export Reference Data...) and can see that many entries are missing when compared with an export from a local *.eap file-base repository. Does anyone have experience fixing this and a list of steps that could be performed?

One specific question I have is whether one can also delete this data in the client (if I compare/merge the xml and end up having a mess, can I cleanup/tune by hand or am I back to a DB-restore ?).

Answer (score 1):

It's not the database setup script that has gone wrong, but rather the initial project transfer.

You basically have two options to fix this.

1. Go back to the last backup you have of the model before you moved to this repository and do a project transfer from this model to your current model. If you export the contents of the current model to xmi first you can then import that into the newly transferred model. This should restore the content.
2. Export the reference data from a model that you know is OK and this into the current model.

The first option is the safest as it will **ensure** that all the tables are correctly filled.

Comment: In earlier versions I had issues with re-importing image reference data. I fixed that with my own import. Not sure how the state is here with that slow fix frequency at Sparx.

Comment: I don't really understand the first answer as we did not transfer any projects to this model. We then imported the reference data from a model that works, but this did not fix the problem completely. Some parts of the EA-installation now show the correct information, but when I look at the basic configuration with SQL queries, there is still a lot missing and we are not able to configure the auto-counters.

Comment: You can't "not transfer" a model into a database repository. That is the only way to start using such a model.

Answer (score -1):

Finally we were not able to fixe the problem by importing more data. We had to reinstall the system and then move our project to it.

I believe it would have been possible to hack the reference data in on DB-level by analysing the original scripts, but I don't have access to the DB.